# MySQL count used in a case query statement

Tags: mysql, count, case

I require this query to execute a `CASE` statement depending on the value returned by `COUNT`:

```
select   @getshift :=  (select(COUNT(*) from `oee_machinenames` where `Shift1` = '06:00:00'))
(Case
When  @getshift >=1 
Then
update `oee_system`.`oee_machinenames` 
set `oee_machinenames`.`default_GM_state` = 0 
where `oee_machinenames`.`Shift1` = '06:00:00'
when @getshift ==0 
then
update `oee_system`.`oee_machinenames` 
set `oee_machinenames`.`default_GM_state` = 9 
where `oee_machinenames`.`Shift1` = '06:00:00' end)
```

The variable @getshift should return the number of count and if this `>= 1` then an update statement occurs, if not then another update statement should occur. I will eventually be using this in a MYSQL time triggered event

**EDIT:** Neither this works as a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`tpm_dev`@`%` PROCEDURE `getshifts`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
select  @getshift := select COUNT(*) from oee_machinenames where oee_machinenames.Shift1 = '06:00:00';
update oee_machinenames
if @getshift >=1 
set default_GM_state = 99;
else
set default_GM_state = 90;
end if
END
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?  Does it have to be a single query?  Running a select and then a separate update will be easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly do a join to a sub query. However you are updating the same table as the sub query uses and MySQL doesn't support that. You can maybe get away with putting an extra sub query to select the results from the sub query to hide the common table from MySQL.

Something like this:-

```
UPDATE oee_system.oee_machinenames a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT aCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS aCount
        FROM oee_machinenames 
        WHERE Shift1 = '06:00:00'
    ) c
) b
set a.default_GM_state = IF(b.aCount = 0, 0, 99) 
WHERE b.aCount >= 0
AND a.Shift1 = '06:00:00'
```

Comment: thanks but I cannot understand the IF(b.aCount = 0, 0, 0)  part. Is it here that I specify if count is more than 1 do update query 1 or else do update query 2....

Comment: Sorry, typo. It is setting default_GM_state to 0 or to 99 depending on the count.